# $G$ contains Hamiltonian circuit $\Leftrightarrow G + uv$ contains Hamiltonian circuit

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

We have graph $G$ and two not connected vertexes $u,v$ where 
$$ \deg(u)+\deg(v) \ge n $$
Prove that $G$ contains Hamiltonian circuit $\Leftrightarrow G + uv$  contains Hamiltonian circuit

### My approach

$\Rightarrow$
This part is easy because we can use old Hamiltonian circuit and everything will works.

$\Leftarrow $ But I stucked on implication on this side - I tried to divide our graph to $3$ parts: $G_1, G_2, G_3$. 

$G_1$ is a part where all vertexes are connected with $u$. 
$G_2$ is a part where all vertexes are connected with $v$. 
$G_3$ is a part where none of vertexes are connected with $u$ or $v$.
I am not sure what give me information about $\deg(u)+\deg(v) \ge n$ because probably it should be used in that step but currently I don't see that.

Comment: I think you need to say what $n$ is.

Comment: This fact is connected to Bondy-Chvatal theorem. See, for example, here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path or here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12819/proof-of-bondy-and-chvátal-theorem

Comment: n is number of vertexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Hamiltonian cycle does not use the edge $uv$ then it is a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.

If the Hamiltonian cycle in $G+uv$ uses the edge $uv$, then there is a Hamiltonian path in $G$ going from $u$ to $v$
$$(u=v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n=v)$$
Consider the two sets
\begin{align*}
P&=\{v_i\mid i\geq 2 \text{ and } uv_i\in G\},\\
Q&=\{v_i\mid i\geq 2 \text{ and } vv_{i-1}\in G\}
\end{align*}
Note that $P=\Gamma_G(u)$ and $\lvert Q\rvert = \lvert\Gamma_G(v)\rvert$, so $\lvert P\rvert+\lvert Q\rvert\geq n$ and since $P\cup Q\subseteq\{v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n\}$ there is a $v_j\in P\cap Q$.  Now
$$
(v_j,u,v_2,\dots,v_{j-1},v=v_n,v_{n-1},\dots,v_{j+1},v_j)
$$
is a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.

Comment: why do you claim with that $v_{j-1} $ is connected with $v$?